# Published site reverts without changes to theme

Tags: themes, cache, publish, staging, production

I recently added a search bar to our website by adding a plugin and adding that plugin into the appropriate place in our theme. I also added an event listener as an attribute on an element in another file.

Seemingly randomly,the site will revert itself on the front-end to an older version of the theme without the searchbar or event listener. The bizarre part, however, is that the theme code does not change at all. If I simply save two of the theme files again (without making any changes to the file itself), the website renders properly. The files themselves never seem to revert.

I'm newer to Wordpress, so I don't fully understand that pipeline yet. Because the code isn't reverting I suspect its a caching problem. But even clearing all the cache files doesn't resolve the problem when it crops up. Only re-saving those files (header.blade.liquid and tax-product-categories.blade.php
(tax-product-categories.blade.php) fixes it. We're using WP-Engine with a staging environment. Even more strangely, the problem has never occurred in the staging environment.

So to summarize:

- Published production randomly reverts
- Theme files do not revert
- Saving the theme files again with or without changing them fixes
  problem
- Clearing caches does not fix the problem

Any thoughts or ideas?